# Android - show footer divider but no list row divider

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view which has a footer.
It displays numbers and at the bottom is the total.

I want to be able to show the rows without a divider between them. OTOH I DO want a divider before the summary row.
Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `android:dividerHeight` to `0` in your list.

Then use custom layout for footer in which you add divider by yourself. For example, that can be a `TextView` with no text, `android:layout_height` set to `2` and `android:background` set to some color.

Comment: Question would be how I would control the length of the divider to match that of the listview.

Comment: By default, divider height equals 1 px. But this can be changed by vendors when they apply their custom themes (like Samsung's TouchWiz or HTC Sense). If you really need exactly the same height, you can call "getDividerHeight" on your ListView and then set same height for your divider of your footer in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

When you have custom layout for the footer, just add divider on top of it. It can be for example View of hight 2dp and different background color.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this programatically, since setting android:dividerHeight="0dip" in the XML didn't work for me:

```
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```